# pregunta jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, jetpack-compose

[image: botones de una calculadora.]

Estoy tratando de hacer una calculadora, pero no logro hacer en compose que cada Box que contiene cada numero sean todos del mismo grosor, lo que hice fue un padding en cada box, pero como ven los numeros quedan mas pequeños, quisiera que todos tengan el mismo tamaño pero sin colocarlos hard coded, si no que tomen todo el espacio que necesiten horizontalmente para que queden iguales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta incluir el código de `rowOne()`, `rowTwo()` y `rowThree()`. Además debes compartir el código en forma de texto, no como imagen. Igual te voy a guiar un poco porque de todas maneras se nota donde está el problema.

El teclado de la calculadora debería estar formado por botones. Usa `Box` cuando necesites poner componentes uno encima de otro.

Para que todos los botones queden del mismo tamaño deberías trabajar con `Column` y `Row` y la propiedad `weight` de los modificadores de los componentes contenidos en ellas.

Por ejemplo, si quieres contener 4 botones en una misma fila y que además toda la fila ocupe el ancho de la pantalla y que la anchura de los botones sea igual, lo debes hacer así:

```
private val BUTTON_FONT_SIZE = 18.sp

...

Row (
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
) {
    Button(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        onClick = {
            //TODO
        }
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "%",
            fontSize = BUTTON_FONT_SIZE,
            modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
        )
    }

    Button(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        onClick = {
            //TODO
        }
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "CE",
            fontSize = BUTTON_FONT_SIZE,
            modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
        )
    }

    Button(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        onClick = {
            //TODO
        }
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "C",
            fontSize = BUTTON_FONT_SIZE,
            modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
        )
    }

    Button(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        onClick = {
            //TODO
        }
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "DEL",
            fontSize = BUTTON_FONT_SIZE,
            modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
        )
    }
}
```

**Nota:** Los tamaños de las fuentes y colores deberían ser manejados desde los Temas. Por mientras puedes declarar el tamaño de la fuente por separado (`BUTTON_FONT_SIZE`) para que lo tengas que cambiar solamente en un solo lugar.

Por último, si ahora quieres que entre cada botón haya una pequeña separación, basta solamente con añadirle `.padding(4.dp)` al modificador de cada botón. Y si además quieres que cada botón sea cuadrado, puedes agregarle al modificador la propiedad `.aspectRatio(1f)`. Al final el modificador de cada botón quedaría así:

```
modifier = Modifier
              .weight(1f)
              .padding(PADDING)
              .aspectRatio(1f)
```

**Nota:** Puedes hacer lo mismo para el padding de los botones y crear una variable privada para que solo lo tengas que cambiar en un solo lugar.

Comment: genial muchas gracias! funciono perfecto!

Answer (score 0):

No sé si ya lo has solucionado, pero te recomiendo usar un LazyVerticalGrid que es como un column pero el interior es una cuadrícula perfecta, y ya con eso solo pones los Box en su interior

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]. Ten en cuenta que si encontro una solucion, ya que hay una respuesta aceptada. Sin embargo, si tienes otro metodo, por favor explica claramente como.